# Is there a way to download a CSV file from "website button click" without using RSelenium in R?

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, data-import

The link is: http://www.b3.com.br/pt_br/produtos-e-servicos/negociacao/renda-variavel/fundos-de-investimentos/fii/fiis-listados/

I have to click in the "Exportar lista completa de Fundos em CSV" button to download the file

For some reason, the only way i could read the page in R was using

```
url = "http://www.b3.com.br/pt_br/produtos-e-servicos/negociacao/renda-variavel/fundos-de-investimentos/fii/fiis-listados/"
download.file(url1, destfile = "scrapedpage.html", quiet=TRUE)

content <- read_html("scrapedpage.html")
```

Comment: Zwirtes, welcome to SO! Can you say a bit more... why do you mention RSelenium? It looks like you were able to grab the file with `utils::download.file()` from base R, is this not the case?

Answer (score 0):

The button "Exportar lista completa de Fundos em CSV" is coming from a different origin, if you open dev tools on chrome you can see that the whole body is in an iframe and its source is https://sistemaswebb3-listados.b3.com.br/fundsPage/7.

I suggest you

1. grab the iframe source first then
2. scrape it to find the link of the btn.

For this case it was https://sistemaswebb3-listados.b3.com.br/fundsProxy/fundsCall/GetListFundDownload/eyJ0eXBlRnVuZCI6NywicGFnZU51bWJlciI6MSwicGFnZVNpemUiOjIwfQ==
this will csv data all you have to do is convert it to csv.

since you can easily get these from website source you can use [cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio) to quickly scrape and grab the item from HTML